# Как получить открытый ключ из структуры DH

Tags: c++, openssl

Пытаюсь испробовать в действии алгоритм Диффи-Хеллмана. Взял код [отсюда](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Diffie_Hellman):

```cpp
DH *privkey;
int codes;
int secret_size;

/* Generate the parameters to be used */
if(NULL == (privkey = DH_new())) handleErrors();
if(1 != DH_generate_parameters_ex(privkey, 2048, DH_GENERATOR_2, NULL)) handleErrors();

if(1 != DH_check(privkey, &codes)) handleErrors();
if(codes != 0)
{
    /* Problems have been found with the generated parameters */
    /* Handle these here - we'll just abort for this example */
    printf("DH_check failed\n");
    abort();
}

/* Generate the public and private key pair */
if(1 != DH_generate_key(privkey)) handleErrors();
```

Далее написано "отправьте открытый ключ второму участнику обмена". Но при попытке получить `privkey->pub_key` Visual Studio выдаёт "использование указателя на тип неполного класса не допускается".

Вопрос: как мне "вытащить" открытый ключ из структуры `DH`?

Comment: подключите соотв. заголовочные файлы openssl  `#include <openssl/dh.h>`, в примере не видно подключено или нет

Comment: @goldstar_labs Подключал, не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Открытый ключ можно получить следующим образом:

```cpp
const BIGNUM * pubKey = BN_new();
DH_get0_key(privkey, &pubKey, nullptr);
```

Если вместо `nullptr` подставить ещё один указатель, подобный `pubKey`, по этому адресу будет записано значение закрытого ключа.